# Inserting an image matrix in a cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, filtering

I have to filter an image multiple times from the same filter. For this I have to make an empty cell C = { [] [] [] [] } and have to process the image from one filter and the output of the filter should be gone to 1st member of cell C(1) and so on.
1. Please direct how to insert image/matrix into a specific position in cell
2. Or simply how to filter an image multiple times from one filter (i.e., each time the output will be filtered). This is like closed loop kind of filtering.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly. So I will try to give detailed example.

Let's imagine you have to apply 3 filters on same data and store output progressively in cell array.

```
Filters=[@filter1,@filter2,@filter3]; % Create array of function handles
OutputCell=cell(1,length(Filters));
for filterIdx=1:length(Filters) % This loop may be vectorized through otpmizations.
   if filterIdx==1
       OutputCell{filterIdx}=Filters(filterIdx)(ImageData); % Function stored in handles array to be called
   else
       OutputCell{filterIdx}=Filters(filterIdx)(OutputCell{filterIdx-1});
   end
end
```